# Hard Drive Serial Number Is Different When NSIS Calls Script

Tags: python, installation, nsis

I have a very weird error occurring. I have a Python script that prints out the user's Hard Drive serial number.

If I run this script in idle (or simply double click the script) it prints out my Hard Drive serial number as: `09sd01u4ctzn`.

**BUT If** my NSIS installer runs that same Python script it prints out my Hard Drive serial number as: `90ds104utcnz`. Ie, each 2 characters are reversed (instead of `09`, its `90` and so on).

**Do you know why this is happening?**

Some important information:

- The NSIS installer runs with elevated privileges (Admin)
- My laptop is 64 bit
- I am using Python 2.7
- If I run the Python script (through Idle) with elevated privileges it still prints out the same serial no. (`09sd01u4ctzn`) so I dont think elevated privileges is the cause.
- Maybe the cause is that WPython.exe is run as UTF-8 (or non-ascii)?
- Maybe the NSIS installer is 64 bit which affects the interpretation of the serial no.?

Heres my simple python script:

```
import wmi
def get_hard_drive_serial():
    c = wmi.WMI()
    for item in c.Win32_PhysicalMedia():
        if "PHYSICALDRIVE" in str(item.Tag).upper():
            return str(item.SerialNumber)

    return None


print "HD Serial as Regular User: " + get_hard_drive_serial()
```

*Note:* Obviously I am not exporting a NSIS installer that calls a python script (because not all windows users have python installed). So I am creating an .exe from that python script and having the NSIS installer call that. I need an external .exe because NSIS has no easy way to determine the users Hard Drive serial no.

**-------------------------------------------------**
Edit:

So I've tested a simple NSIS script and python script. The NSIS script calls the python script using `EXECWAIT`. As you can see the serial no. is different when the script is called by NSIS than if it is called by itself OR though a C# program (I've tested that also).

Any ideas what on earth is going on?

```
InstallDir  "abc"
Name        "def"        
OutFile     "def.exe"

Section
    DetailPrint "Hello World"

    ExecWait '"cmd.exe" /k' # Then type GetMACAddress.py in cmd (make sure python script is in same dir as the installer)

SectionEnd
```

GetMACAddress.py

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for item in c.Win32_PhysicalMedia():
    if "PHYSICALDRIVE" in str(item.Tag).upper():
        print item.Tag + ", " + item.SerialNumber

raw_input("Pause")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to use WMI in NSIS, just do a search on the NSIS wiki and forum.

My guess is that WPython is the cause of the flipped nibbles. It is very unlikely that just because NSIS is the parent process something would change in the python part. You could try adding `Exec '"cmd.exe" /k'` to your installer and then run the WPython application from there and see what happens...

Comment: thanks for the advice. I am certain that this is a NSIS specific problem (or the mode that NSIS is run in - 64bit/32bit mode. etc.). Please see my edit and run it for yourself.